# Joomla class autoloading

Tags: php, joomla, autoload

I'm trying to extend a Joomla class, and I know that Joomla supports autoloading of classes.

But if I have a class like

```
class MyClass extends JModelList
```

where do I need to save this file so it gets picked up automatically and I don't need to require it on every other class that uses it?

NOTE: I'm working within the context of a component so I can't just add my new class to the Joomla core libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');
```

Comment: can you explain your answer a bit? Where would this jimport statement go and where does the new class get saved within the component hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Well that looks like you're creating a `model` using `JModelList` as the parent.

Joomla! generally uses a one class per file approach, with components structured like this:

```
/components
    /com_mycomponent
        /models
        /controllers
```

Model files generally reside in the `/models` directory of your component, if they are named correctly (class and file) and used by the `view` to retrieve an item in the `display()` like this `$this->item = $this->get('Item');` you don't have to take any other action unless you're loading secondary or unrelated models.

Usually model files are named in relation to the class name, e.g. the standard `article` model has a class of `ContentModelArticle` and the file `article.php` found in:

```
/components/com_content/models/article.php
```

I would suggest that you use the [Developer Portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aDevelopers) on [Joomla's Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/) site and read up on [Component Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aComponent_Development), there's a range of tutorials on components development. This section deals with [adding models to the site section of your component](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_model_to_the_site_part), there's also an article on [using multiple models in a MVC component](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component).